# Action acting on multiple stores

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers, redux-framework

I have an action that needs to flow data in its own store but also in a config store. I need this because the data added is different & it also get cleared differently.

I'm wondering in that case if it would be better to use combine reducers? Or acting on multiple store is an acceptable solution?

```
import { PAGE_CHANGE_TITLE } from 'actions/types/page.types';
import { PROJECT_SELECTED } from 'actions/types/projects.types';

const initialState = {
  pages: {
    last: {},
    current: {},
    last5: [],
  },
  project: localStorage.getItem('project') || {},
};

export function configs(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

  case PAGE_CHANGE_TITLE:

    const last5 = [...state.pages.last5];
    last5.unshift(action.data);
    if (last5.length > 5) {
      last5.pop();
    }

    return {
      ...state,
      pages: {
        last: {
          ...state.pages.current,
        },
        current: {
          ...action.data,
        },
        last5: last5,
      },
    };

  case PROJECT_SELECTED:
    return {
      ...state,
      project: {
        ...action.data,
      },
    };

  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reducer composition, whether with `combineReducers()` or some manual approach. It is very common to have [different reducers handling the same action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494345/458193).

In Redux, [we almost never suggest you to use multiple stores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33633850/458193).