# How to dispatch an action when clicking on Link when using React-Router & Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Let's say I have a `Link` that sends me to a page for adding/editing a list entry.

How do I dispatch a Redux action when I click on the `Link` itself  so that I can update the Redux store first, before actually getting redirected to that page.

Eg:
I click on Edit button -> Action is dispatched -> Store updated, `{'state': 'edit-mode'}` -> Proceed to redirect.

Or do you have another way in mind to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Maybe when component has mounted, then I will run an action like `stateToEdit` based on certain conditions? If so, then please show to me your way. Thanks

PS: I'm using only one component for all add/edit/delete. So I'm thinking of a way to render based on the `state` whether its on `edit-mode` or `delete-mode` etc.

Comment: Instead of using `Link`, you could use `browserHistory.push(path)` with on `onClick` function. Inside this function, dispatch your action, then push to the new location.

Comment: I was also thinking of something like that but I'm not too sure if this is the right way to solve the problem. I guess I'll use this method for now. If there are other ways, then I'd like to know. Thanks

Comment: A more appropriate way to address this issue might be to introduce `redux-thunk` which would probably help organize the code a bit more considering you probably want to perform this "dispatch something, then move to another page" action in various places. Take a peek at Dan's answer here, I'm sure it'll get the gears turning for how you could approach the issue in your context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493352/can-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-without-redux-thunk-middleware/35642783#35642783

Comment: ^ As in, envision replacing one of those `dispatch(increment)` calls with a call to `browserHistory`

Comment: Thanks for the reply & info. Can you put your replies as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are a couple ways you could go about addressing this issue:

1. Instead of using `Link`, try utilizing `browserHistory.push(path)` with an `onClick` function.

   - Inside the `onClick`, you can `dispatch` your action, then `push` to a new location.
   - However, if you want to perform this series of actions in various components, you will probably suffer from code duplication.
2. A more robust way to address this issue would be to implement `redux-thunk`, which provides a generic way of performing multiple "actions" (be it calling a Redux action, or performing an async operation, or both!) in response to a change.

   - Dan has a great response here highlighting the simplicity of what `redux-thunk` actually offers: [Can I dispatch multiple actions without Redux Thunk middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493352/can-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-without-redux-thunk-middleware/35642783#35642783)
   - In your case, in the `incrementTwice` function, imagine just replacing one of the `dispatch(increment)` calls with a call to `browserHistory.push(action.path)`, similar to the below:

**Redux thunk action**

```
export const dispatchThenRoute = (myAction, myPath) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(myAction)
        browserHistory.push(myPath);
    }
};
```

Comment: Link Prefetch won't work if we go with this approach. Am I correct? Or how to make it work!

Comment: In `react-router` v4 there is no `browserHistory`: how to deal with the dispatching and then the pushing if there is nothing to push to?

Comment: @Aerendir You can connect a component to the Router by using the `withRouter(App)` HOC. After this, `App` now access access to `location` and `history` in `props`. Just push to history as you normally would. Example `export default withRouter(App);` via https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate/blob/master/src/components/App.jsx

Comment: What's wrong with `<Link to="mypath" onClick={this.props.dispatchAction.bind(this)}>...`?

Comment: @Sumit You could do that, but you'll double route if you pass your own `onClick` that pushes to a location (See https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js).

Comment: @Sumit Also, if you're `onClick` performs an async action, there's no guarantee if it will complete by the time the new location is pushed in `<Link />`. With a thunk, you can control the flow.